# How to use initialValues inside a Wizard with PrefixedField (React Final Form)?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using React Final Form to create a multi-step wizard form.

I need to pass initialValues into my Wizard, which I can using the Field Component.
However, I want to use PrefixedField instead, which provides a "prefix wrapper" to better structure my form data. Unfortunately, when I use PrefixedField, the initialValues props doesn't work.

```
<Wizard
  initialValues={{
     nomeCompleto: "Lois S",
   }}
   onSubmit={onSubmit}
   >
   <Wizard.Page>
      <FieldPrefix prefix="dadosCliente">
         <label htmlFor="nomeCompleto" className="form-label">
             Nome Completo
         </label>
          <PrefixedField
            name="nomeCompleto"
            className="form-control"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Nome Completo"
            validate={required}
            />
            <Error name="firstName" />
```

The code used for the PrefixedFields is exactly the same used on [Prefixed Fields Example of React Final Form docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-prefixed-fields-seiy8)

```
/************ IMPORTANT CODE STARTS HERE **************/
const FieldPrefixContext = React.createContext();
const FieldPrefix = ({ prefix, children }) => (
  <FieldPrefixContext.Provider value={prefix}>
    {children}
  </FieldPrefixContext.Provider>
);
const PrefixedField = ({ name, ...props }) => (
  <FieldPrefixContext.Consumer>
    {prefix => <Field name={`${prefix}.${name}`} {...props} />}
  </FieldPrefixContext.Consumer>
);
/************* IMPORTANT CODE ENDS HERE ***************/
```

What am I doing wrong here or should I do it in another way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just needed to add the prefix to my `initialValues`.

Working code:

```
<Wizard
  initialValues={{
     dadosCliente:{
        nomeCompleto: "Lois S",
     }
   }}
   onSubmit={onSubmit}
   >
   <Wizard.Page>
      <FieldPrefix prefix="dadosCliente">
       <PrefixedField id="nomeCompleto" name="nomeCompleto" validate={required}>
          {({ input, meta }) => (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="nomeCompleto" className="form-label">
                Nome Completo
              </label>
              <input
                {...input}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Nome Completo"
                component="input"
                className="form-control"
              />
              {meta.error && meta.touched && (
                <FieldError message={meta.error}></FieldError>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </PrefixedField >
      ...
```